# Javascript dataURL POST to PHP not working

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to post dataURL over to php but with no succsess.
My .js file is as follow.

```
var dataURL = signaturePad.toDataURL();
alert(dataURL);
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "test.php", 
    data: { 
    imgBase64: dataURL 
    } 
    }).done(function(o) { 
      console.log('saved');
      alert(o); 
    });
```

alert(dataURL) output is as follow;

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAhkAAADZCAYAAACNbSIWAAAeW.....
```

test.php

```
<?php
if($_POST['imgBase64']) { 
$img = $_POST['imgBase64'];
}
else{
$img = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAhkAAADZCAYAAACNbSIWAAAeW.....";
}
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$fileData = base64_decode($img);
//saving
$timestamp = date('YmdHis');
$fileName = ''.$timestamp.'.png';
echo"$fileData";
file_put_contents($fileName, $fileData);
?>
```

In my php file I have entered the value of my alert for testing purposes. Now my php page is working 100% due to the test and passing no value from my .js function. but with the correct value it's not even posting to my php page, only when I remove all not standard characters from the dataURL then it post but obvious with corrupt data.

To avoid further confusion the following code works 100%, the .js and the php. where var dataURL = signaturePad.toDataURL(); is passed to the function

```
function postData(data) {
    alert(data);
    var desired = data.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "test.php", 
        data: { 
        imgBase64: desired 
        } 
    }).done(function(o) { 
       console.log('saved');
       alert(o); 
    }); 
}
```

So the problem is the .js will not post with the given dataUrl due to special characters, but I cant remove them.. I even tried var desired = encodeURIComponent(data); witch I can at least decode on the php page but this also does not want to post.

Comment: You send data with the key `imgBase64`, but you try to detect `$_POST['image']`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and apologies foe the confusion (I have corrected this). I have deliberately called $_POST['image'] to test the call to the php page and test the code with the "fall-over" image. As mentioned in the last paragraph the .js function is not triggered at all when trying to post "dataURL". Only after a number of tests it will only trigger after running dataURL.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') to remove all special characters. Witch obviously will break my image..

Comment: Here's an idea - replace special characters with some other string and then replace them back in php. See if that works as a temporary hack until you figure out what's causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies..

I ended up creating a blob first and posting the blob.

```
function dataURLToBlob(dataURL) {
  var parts = dataURL.split(';base64,');
  var contentType = parts[0].split(":")[1];
  var raw = window.atob(parts[1]);
  var rawLength = raw.length;
  var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(rawLength);

  for (var i = 0; i < rawLength; ++i) {
    uInt8Array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
  }


  return new Blob([uInt8Array], { type: contentType }); 



    $.post("test2.php",
    {
      name: uInt8Array
    },
    function(data,status){
      alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data: { 
    imgBase64: data
    //send key is imgBase64 and data value is undefined in given scope
    //replace data with dataURL
}
```

And in php file change this `$_POST['image']` to `$_POST['imgBase64']`

Comment: Thank you for the reply and apologies foe the confusion (I have corrected this). I have deliberately called $_POST['image'] to test the call to the php page and test the code with the "fall-over" image. As mentioned in the last paragraph the .js function is not triggered at all when trying to post "dataURL". Only after a number of tests it will only trigger after running dataURL.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') to remove all special characters. Witch obviously will break my image..